# Exception has occurred: AttributeError module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping' after sudo pip install

Tags: python, pip, permissions, root

I accidentally used sudo pip install, and afterwards found that it is a very bad practice.

I saw the below warning in the end of running sudo pip install.

`Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv`

And then receiving error whenever I try to run "import xxx" in my python code

`Exception has occurred: AttributeError module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping'` after sudo pip install

I am using MacOS, I think I've messed up my computer... Anyone please help..

I read this post, but didn't help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1158271/how-to-fix-pip-after-running-it-with-sudo

My terminal did not return any file related to Python after running the code in above post
`sudo find $HOME \! -user $USER -print | xargs ls -ld`

Comment: **1**. The problem is not related to `sudo` at all; see https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+AttributeError+module+collections+has+no+attribute+MutableMapping **2**. I think your `find` command can be simplified as `sudo find ~ \! -user $USER -ls`

Comment: It merely run on Python 3.10 or later, Doesn't work on older version < than 3.10.

Comment: @phd @toyota-supra But my problem only started to appear after I ran the `sudo pip3 install`. My code and interpreter didn't change. So I suspect that command was causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

It was caused since the installation of package changed the version of another pre-requisite package. The version gap was causing the error `Exception has occurred: AttributeError module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping' after sudo pip install`.

Fix: I gave up on using that package, and reverted the changes it made, including the version and root ownership of all related pre-requisite packages.